# How to disable spring batch 5 metadata table calls or entries

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How to disable spring batch metadata table calls or entries in Spring 5 through xml configuration or Java configuration ?

Spring 5 uses JobRepositoryFactoryBean which uses dataSource for db and it starts creating tables and entries once batch runs. I would like to avoid that creation and entries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable meta-data, a Spring Batch job requires a job repository to report its meta-data to. You can use an in-memory database for the job repository like H2, HSQLDB, etc. Otherwise, you can implement `JobRepository` yourself and choose to use something different than a database.